# Insertar array en tabla MySQL con Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario como este:

[image: Formulario]

Lo que quiero es que al momento de seleccionar dos deportes o más, se agregue una fila por cada deporte con el id del nombre seleccionado, hasta el momento en mi base de datos se almacena así:

[image: DB]

Y aquí está mi código del Controller:

```
$data = new Id;
  if(isset($_POST["save"])){
    $names = $_POST["names"];
    $sports =$_POST["sports"];
    $array = implode(', ', $sports);
    $data->name = $names;
    $data->sport = $array;
    $data->save();
    $ids = Id::all();
    return view('data', ['ids'=>$ids]);
  }
```

Comment: Puedes poner el metodo completo de ese controlador??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A eloquent puedes pasarle un array multidimensional para hacer multiples insert.

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

/* Incluye Query Builder */
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/* Incluye Request */
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/* Incluye tu modelo de Eloquent */
use App\MiModelo;

class MiclaseController extends Controller
{

    public function miMetodo(Request $request /* aqui recibes los datos*/ )
    {
        /* Se debe construir un array como este 
        $data = array(
            array('columna'=> 'valor', 'columna2'=> 'valor 2'), 
            array('name'=> 1, 'sport'=> 5),
            array('name'=> 1, 'sport'=> 8),

        );
        */

        /* declaramos el array */
        $datos_a_insertar = array();

        /* añadimos los datos al array */
        foreach ($request->sports as $key => $sport) 
        {
            $datos_a_insertar[$key]['name'] = $request->names;
            $datos_a_insertar[$key]['sport'] = $sport;
        }

        /* Luego simplemente lo insertamos con Eloquent o con Query Builder */
        /* con Eloquent */
        MiModelo::insert($datos_a_insertar); 
        /* o con Query Builder */
        DB::table('table')->insert($datos_a_insertar); 

        /* Retonamos la vista o lo que corresponda */
        return view('miVista');
    }


}
```

Por cierto no necesitas utilizar el array $_POST o $_GET directamente, de hecho es desaconsejable, pues de hacerlo no podras aprovechar las capas de validación que provee laravel por ejemplo.

Comment: Una pequeña recomendación sin ninguna implicación técnica o de desempeño, simplemente de estilo: inicializa los arreglos con `[]`.

Comment: @Shaz  Y eso ¿por algún motivo concreto? Me parece más legible inicializarlo con array();

Comment: No, no hay ningún motivo concreto, es como usar if y else en vez del operador ternario para condiciones simples. Aunque no está explícitamente definido, en PSR-2 utlizan `[]` para los arrays: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#43-methods

Comment: Y a partir de PSR-3 https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md utilizan **array()**, la idea es utilizar un leguaje mas narrativo que describa por si mismo lo que es, aun que no conozcas el lenguaje en si mismo.

Comment: La diferencia es que psr-3 no es una guía de estilo. Bueno, igual estos comentarios no son para discutir, tal vez algún día lo podamos debatir en un chat. Buen día.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco laravel, pero deberías hacer algo así:

```
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
    $names = $_POST["names"];
    $sports =$_POST["sports"];
    foreach($sports => $sport) {
        $data = new Id;
        $data->name = $names;
        $data->sport = $sport;
        $data->save();
    }    
    $ids = Id::all();
    return view('data', ['ids'=>$ids]);
  }
```

Esto es, en vez de hacer un implode de los sports, los recorres con un for y los insertas uno por uno.

Sin embargo, si queres guardar un id por cada row, asegúrate que el tipo de dato de la tabla sea int, y no varchar.

---

ACTUALIZACION:
Asegurate también que los checkbox del formulario en el html sean de tipo array. O sea, agregarle los corchetes al final del name. Algo asi:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="1"> Soccer
<input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="2"> Tochito
```

.... etc.

Comment: ya lo intenté así, inlcuso hice lo que me dijiste de cambiar a tipo int, pero ahora sólo guarda el último deporte que se seleccionó, en vez de todos los seleccionados

Comment: Hola Paloma, ahi te actualize la respuesta. Fíjate si los inputs son de tipo array.

Comment: Hola Federico, también los tiene.